# My first MVVM application architecture setup

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, prism

Ok, time is coming for my first WPF project :). I work before with Flex and PureMVC and I know how project setup is important in RIA's. I decided to work with MVVM. And decided to work with PRISM framework. Application is somethin like operating system. There will be 'shell' (parent for smaller applications). Smaller application I plan to make like modules. So I plan to design structure of project something like this.

> Module_A {view, viewModel, model,
>   assets} // for example calculator
>   Module_B {view, viewModel, model,
>   assets} // notebook

etc
I read prism doc and I see that parrent for all this modules should be shell project, and this is my main question here.

> Parrent_Project {App.xaml,
>   Bootstrapper.cs, Shell.xaml}

Because this shell will be fullscreen with background images (like operating system), right click with some features. Is that ok to create folder structure like in modulesXYZ for Shell.xaml here? I want to start project with good structure so any advice is welcome. Thanks

Maybe I was not clear. Can I use Shell to add it some functionality (in MVVM manner) like set it to fullscreen, always on top etc. Or not?

I want to shell be in full kiosk mode. And I did somethong about it with folowing code. But when I press alt + tab, win key or other taskbar goes ove my app. Is there any solution for this:

```
public class Interop
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        public static IntPtr GetWindowHandle(Window window)
        {
            return new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
        }
    }

public Shell()
        {            
            InitializeComponent();



            IntPtr window = Interop.GetWindowHandle(this);
            IntPtr focused = Interop.GetForegroundWindow();
            if (window != focused)
            {
                Interop.SetForegroundWindow(window);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve the effects you desire is by configuring the shell.  Specifically, setting the following values in `Shell.xaml` will nominally provide the desired result:

```
<Window ... WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized" Topmost="True>
```

and if these properties don't need to change then this approach is already MVVM friendly as it is purely a view issue.

Comment: Ok thanks you lead me to good way. But I have one minor problem. I some details in question, can you please check.

Comment: It would be better to change the way your application is launched than to try to prevent an Explorer which is always running from ever showing.  To do this **replace** Explorer with your application as the logon shell.  This is a simple registry setting.

Comment: I'am sorry, I google all day but I cant find any useful explanation. Can you provide some link or code for start point how to prevent user from leaving application by pressing keys?

Comment: Nowadays most people call it "Kiosk Mode".  Here's a starting point: http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7desktop/thread/89f3246f-baaf-45fc-b946-07450475a5b0